# when i print tableview it show a black page in pdf file in javafx .why?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

This is my code:

```
    try {
        formList = ConnectionAndQueries.fillFormTable();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    tableView.setItems(formList);

printAllBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            //tableView.setItems(formList);
            Stage dialogStage=new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
          PrinterJob printerJob=PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
          if (printerJob != null) {
            tableView.setScaleX(0.75);
            tableView.setScaleY(0.80);
            tableView.setTranslateX(-70);
            tableView.setTranslateY(-50);
            if (printerJob.showPrintDialog(dialogStage) && printerJob.printPage(tableView)) {
              printerJob.endJob();
            }
            tableView.setScaleX(1.0);
            tableView.setScaleY(1.0);
            tableView.setTranslateX(-0);
            tableView.setTranslateY(-0);
          }
         else {
            Alert alert=new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Kein Drucker");
            alert.setHeaderText("Druckerfehler.");
            alert.setContentText("Es wurde kein Drucker gefunden.");
            alert.showAndWait();
          }
        }
    });
```

and i get the table from fxml file.
it shows up like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzkuF.png)

thanks in advance